# Jquery form submit of ASP.Net form : request(txtname) <> txtname.text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to do something that should be simple. I have found  [shortcut.js](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/shortcut.js)
and am using it to fulfill a request. I need to do a page save when they press/type  CTL-S.  A normal odl school synchronous call is fine.

[Yes, CTL-S would normally save the HTML page to a file.]

First I will explain the issue, then I will walk through the particulars.
Here is the js snippet that binds the shortcut. Simply call the buttons click event...

```
 shortcut.add("F11",  function(){
                      $('#ctl00$cp1$btnSave').click();
                         }
             );
```

Upon invoking the shortcut, the keystrokes are captured and the save button is fired. My code behind is called.

**It seems the FORM values in the HTTP request are not getting mapped to the control variables.** I may not quite be saying that right... consider this :
here ctl00$cp1$txtname is the uniqueId of the textBox control.

```
request('ctl00$cp1$txtname') = "newValue"
txtname.text = "oldvalue"
```

If I go back and click on the button w my mouse, same button, same form....

```
request('ctl00$cp1$txtname') = "newValue"
txtname.text = "newvalue"
```

This is the case in form.load. So whenever this mapping is happening/not happening, it is pretty early in the page life cycle.
This is not unique to a particular control. All the controls suffer the same issue.

here is the SAVE  button at design time

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server"
        Text="Save" class="submit" CssClass="buttonblue" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

here is what it looks like when it is rendered

```
<input type="button" name="ctl00$cp1$btnSave" value="Save" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cp1$btnSave','')" id="ctl00_cp1_btnSave" class="buttonblue">
```

I notice that at a DOM level of thinking,  a mouse click should fire __doPostBack. No more, no less. So I change the shortcut code to do the same

```
 shortcut.add("F11",  function(){
                      __doPostBack('ctl00$cp1$btnSave', '');
                         }
             );
```

This does not resolve the problem. 
Again, this is client side stuff, nothing really tricky going on. A look at the page source shows __doPostBack   is rendered this way

```
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

While I am at it , I also try

```
 shortcut.add("F11",  function(){
                      $('#aspnetForm').submit();
                         }
             );
```

this also does not resolve the problem.

I'm not trying to do anything clever, or even asynch, I just want the form to submit via JS.

**My primary question is : why is asp.net not behaving as I would expect it to.
Specifically, why is it not mapping the request.form values to the control variables.**

I would think that 
a) clicking the button 
b) calling  (#btn).click()
c) calling  __doPostback   (with exactly the same parms that clicking would use)

would yield identical results.

I am failing to understand something here.

An interesting data point is that I get the same  unwanted  behavior by calling ('#form').submit()

Answer (score 0):

telerik radTextBox controls somehow interfere with the asp.net process.  By replacing them with regular text boxes, I was able to get the desired behavior.

this has been a thorn in my side for weeks.